# Cannot resolve com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+

Tags: android

I launched my android studio and found that the following lines in the dependencies section of build.gradle are not compiling:

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:6.5.+'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:6.5.+'
```

Gradle Sync tells me that it cannot resolve the packages. I know the newest version of play-services is 7.8.0 but I'm not sure if this is related to that in any way. Any advice?

EDIT: I should mention that if I use 7.8.0, gradle does not complain, as it can find the package. However the methods I am using in my app that pertain to play services become invalid, as Google has updated how their Cloud Messaging works.

Comment: Try navigating to `<Android-sdk>\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services-identity\6.5.87` and see if the .aar and .pom files are there. Try Invalidate cache and restart.

Comment: @EugenPechanec I wasn;t sure how to Invalidate cache, but I followed your suggestion and it worked. In path/to/play-services-identity, there was a directory for 6.5.87 and several directories for 7.0.x. In addition, the maven-metadata.xml was pointing to 7.0.x. I removed the 7.0.x directories and modified maven-metadata.xml to point to 6.5.87 and was successful.

Thank you very much!

Comment: I might be wrong but i think `maven-metadata.xml` should (in optimal case) contain all the available versions so they can be looked up using the `+` sign. Also meaning if you specified directly `6.5.87` as the version you wanted, there would be no error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the folder 
`Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-base` open the maven-metadata.xml file

and add the `<version>6.5.87</version>` under section `<versions>`. It may look like below

```
<versions>
<version>6.5.87</version>
<version>7.0.0</version>
<version>7.3.0</version>
<version>7.5.0</version>
</versions>
```

Do the same for `Android/Sdk/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-identity`

Note: Usually Android SDK in your HOME folder.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to download the play services package.

Go to `Tools` -> `Android` -> `SDKManager`

In the Extra section at the bottom of the list, make sure you have `Google Play Services` marked as installed.

If you use the latest android studio, once you open the SDKManager, go to the SDK Tools and make sure Google Play Services is checked.

Comment: Google Play Services is installed. I have Google Play services, rev 26 installed.

Comment: @ShahbazSheikh You actually need Google Repository not Google Play Services (which is just the latest version provided as an Eclipse project).

Comment: @EugenPechanec I have Google Repository, rev 21 installed. Also, please see the edit to my main post.

Comment: For future readers, see EugenPechanec's comment to the top post for the solution.